# Cordova - download with direct link

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-plugin-file

I want a direct download from an external link in my project. however, when I click the link, Chrome, Explorer browser opens first. Then the file begins to descend.

The platform and plugins I use in the project are below.
I would like your support.

[image: My plugins and platforms]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
                <a href="http://www.kiajans.com.tr/a/uploaded.rar">Download link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
                
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.kiajans.com.tr/a/cmd.PNG

Comment: `href` on urls always open in browser or in web view itself. If you need to download directily from the app, you will have to follow the instructions in https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#example-1
The above must take place during the onclick action of your anchor